# Can we rename the label of "Close Date" field to something else (Target Date) on opportunity for a specific record type?

Tags: record-type, configuration, standard-field

I want to rename "Close Date" as "Target Date" on opportunity for particular record type so is there any solution for it?

Answer (score 1):

You can change the standard field label using the Rename Tabs and Labels option in the setup. but you can't rename the standard field label based on the record type. If you change the standard field label here then it will be applicable for all record types and all page layouts.

For more information refer to this documentation: [Rename Object, Tab, and Field Labels](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.customize_rename.htm&type=5)

Also, check [Considerations for Renaming Tab and Field Labels.](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.customize_rename_considerations.htm&type=5)

[image]